# Why double click instead of single?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have one JFrame where I enter parameters of a matrix, after those parameters being entered, the user is supposed to click a button to start a simulation. The problem is, the button is supposed to be clicked twice instead of once in order to open the JOption pane where a message is written. I just can't figure out why this happens. This is the function that is called from the simulation button's action performed function:

```
private void setMatrixParameters(){
    if(tfTouristNumber.getText().equals("") || tfRowNumber.getText().equals("") || tfColumnNumber.getText().equals("") || tfMinimal.getText().equals("")){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All fields must be filled", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    //check the matrix dimensions
    else if(min + touristNumber > Integer.parseInt(tfRowNumber.getText()) * Integer.parseInt(tfColumnNumber.getText())){
        int dimension= min + touristNumber;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Matrix dimensions too small. Need to be at least:" + dimension, "Enlarge matrix!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    else{
        this.touristNumber = Integer.parseInt(tfTouristNumber.getText());
        int row = Integer.parseInt(tfRowNumber.getText());
        int column = Integer.parseInt(tfColumnNumber.getText());
        this.matrix = new Object[row][column];
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(tfMinimal.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the code you've posted has anything to do with clicking.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool I know, but I have nothing else called from the action performed function. It should work on one click, just like any other button in my application works. I just can't figure out the problem.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to happen. From just the code you've posted, that button click does nothing more than validate and read the inputs of some text fields into local fields. Regardless of how many times you click that button, that's all that's going to happen.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool When I enter the matrix dimensions that are not sufficient, a JOptionPane should pop up giving me a warning. Now, when I enter those dimensions and click the button, nothing happens. Only when I click it again the JOptionPane pops up. I want it to pop up immediately when the button is clicked, not after two clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in this case is that you are not checking the text field values in the second if-condition. The following should do the trick.

```
private void setMatrixParameters(){
    if(tfTouristNumber.getText().equals("") || tfRowNumber.getText().equals("") || tfColumnNumber.getText().equals("") || tfMinimal.getText().equals("")){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All fields must be filled", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      return;
    }

    // Read values here. (Should probably add a try-catch block around this, in case it can't be parsed as number)
    int inTouristNumber = Integer.parseInt(tfTouristNumber.getText());
    int inRow = Integer.parseInt(tfRowNumber.getText());
    int inColumn = Integer.parseInt(tfColumnNumber.getText());
    int inMin = Integer.parseInt(tfMinimal.getText());

    //check the matrix dimensions
    if(inMin + inTouristNumber > inRow * inColumn){
        int dimension= inMin + inTouristNumber;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Matrix dimensions too small. Need to be at least:" + dimension, "Enlarge matrix!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else{
        this.touristNumber = inTouristNumber;
        this.matrix = new Object[inRow][inColumn];
        this.min = inMin;
    }
}
```